# Do graph databases have problems with aggregation operations?

Tags: performance, neo4j, graph-databases

I came across multiple opinions that graph databases tend to have problems with aggregation operations. Like if you have a set of users and want to get maximum age, RDBMS will outperform graph database. Is true and if it is, what is the reason behind it? As far as I understand, key difference between relational and graph database is that each graph database node somehow includes references to the nodes it is connected to. How does it impact "get max age"-like query?

Disclaimer: most of what I have read was about Neo4j, but I suppose if these limitations exist, they should apply to any graph db.

Comment: I have updated my answer, please take a look.

Comment: The InfiniteGraph graph database handles a broad range of aggregation operations very well.

Answer (score 0):

The use of graph databases like Neo4j is recommended when dealing with connected data and complex queries.

The book [Learning Neo4j](https://neo4j.com/learning-neo4j-book/) by Rik Van Bruggen state that you should not use graph databases when dealing with simple, aggregate-oriented queries:

From the book:

> (...) simple queries, where write patterns and read patterns align to
>   the aggregates that we are trying to store, are typically served quite
>   inefficiently in a graph, and would be more efficiently handled by an
>   aggregate-oriented Key-Value or Document store. If complexity is low,
>   the advantage of using a graph database system will be lower too.

The reason behind this is highly related to the nature of the persistence model. Its more easy to make a `sum`, `max` or `avg` operation over a tabled data than a data stored as graph.

Comment: It looks like another solid source of that opinion, but I was searching for a bit more insight look. At physical level graph database has to have some kind of file with list of nodes, what is the problem with finding `max` value in it, comparing to relational table? Especially if you have necessary index (which Neo4j allows you to).

Comment: @Yarrow good point of view. Yes, Neo4j has a file called `neostore.nodestore.db` to store nodes. But this file has only references to other files, like `neostore.propertystore.db` where properties are stored. This way I think the downside is also related to the fact that Neo4j needs to follow this reference first. Also, traditional RDBMS systems have a static and well defined structure while Neo4j implements a flexible schema. This way nodes (even those who have same labels) can have different properties. I thinks this characteristic turns hard the work of computing aggregate operations.

Comment: Storing properties and nodes separately is neo4j specific I guess, but  flexible schema should be more generic problem. Both points sound convincing, though.